# Java Wrapper. Не доступны сетевые ресурсы

Tags: java, java-ee, jvm, windows-service

Здравствуйте.

Для работы jar как сервиса windows попробовал использовать java wrapper.
Приложение запустилось нормально.
В приложении есть обращение к сетевой папке.
Приложение возвращает ошибку о том, что сетевая папка не существует.
НО если приложение запустить не через wrapper, то все работает.
Пробовал сервис запускать от своего доменного пользователя (если запускать под ним, то все работает), результат отрицательный.
Пробовал также шару подключать как сетевой диск, НО результат тоже отрицательный.
Прошу помочь решить проблему.

Заранее благодарю за помощь.

Comment: ну ты хотя бы код приложил с трейсом

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил путем смены логики работы с Samba Linux.

перешел на fileToGet и BufferedInputStream/BufferedOutputStream

```
            NtlmPasswordAuthentication auth = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication("", Samba_User, Samba_Password);
            // папка откуда забирать
            String SambaURL = "smb://" + args[0];
            // папка куда копировать
            File destinationFolder = new File(args[1]);
            File file = new File(args[2]);

            System.out.println("Запущено с параметрами.");
            System.out.println("Samba с файлами: " + SambaURL);
            System.out.println("Локальная папка с файлами для обработки: " + destinationFolder);
            System.out.println("Log работы в файл: " + file);
            System.out.println("Чтение файлов в папке Samba: " + SambaURL);
            // создаем папку если ее нет
            if (!destinationFolder.exists()) {
                destinationFolder.mkdirs();
            }
            SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS_");
            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss dd.MM.yyyy");
            Date date = new Date();
            int StartTime = (int) new Date().getTime();
            String StartDateTime = dateFormat.format(date);
            SmbFile dir = new SmbFile(SambaURL, auth);
            for (SmbFile f : dir.listFiles()) {

                try {

                    child = new File(destinationFolder + "/" + f.getName());
                    fileToGet = new SmbFile(SambaURL + f.getName(), auth);
                    fileToGet.connect();

                    in = new BufferedInputStream(new SmbFileInputStream(fileToGet));
                    out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(child));

                    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
                    int len = 0; //Read length
                    while ((len = in.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) != -1) {
                        out.write(buffer, 0, len);
                    }
                    out.flush(); //The refresh buffer output stream
                    try {
                        printlnAppen(file, "[" + StartDateTime + "]: Скопирован файл - " + f.getName() + ".");
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    String msg = "The error occurred: " + e.getLocalizedMessage();
                    System.out.println(msg);
                } finally {
                    try {
                        if (out != null) {
                            out.close();
                        }
                        if (in != null) {
                            in.close();
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }
                }
```